# IdentityServer4 ADFS External Not Returning Roles

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, adfs, asp.net-core-identity

I have created an IdentityServer4 IDP using the standard template for Core Identity.  I am looking to have an External provider being out ADFS 2016 Server.  I have added this to the AddAuthentication() in Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddOpenIdConnect("adfs", "ADFS", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                    options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;

                    options.Authority = "[AuthURL]";
                    options.ClientId = "[ClientId]";
                    options.ResponseType = "id_token token code";
                    options.Scope.Add("profile");
                    options.Scope.Add("email");

                    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-adfs";
                    options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-callback-adfs";
                    options.RemoteSignOutPath = "/signout-adfs";

                    options.ClaimActions.Add(new JsonKeyClaimAction("role", null, "role")); 

                     options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                     {
                         NameClaimType = "name",
                         RoleClaimType = "role"
                     }; 

                });
```

It successfully redirects to the ADFS login window.  Once signed in it calls the ExternalController.cs CallBack() correctly and I do have a successful authentication.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Callback()
        {
            // read external identity from the temporary cookie
            var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
            if (result?.Succeeded != true)
            {
                throw new Exception("External authentication error");
            }
```

The issue I am having is that I am not getting back the full user.  I see claims but I do not see roles.  I am used to seeing a JWT token which includes a list of Roles, however, I do not see these roles within the Result from above.

[image]

How can I either get a JWT token back from the Authentication against ADFS or have the roles returned and be within the Result?

Answer (score 0):

Inside OIDC add scope for roles:

```
options.Scope.Add("roles");
```

Inside config.cs in IDS4 make sure your client has the allowed scopes:

```
AllowedScopes =
            {
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess, 
                "roles",
            },
```

If it's an API, make sure config.cs has the correct userclaims:

```
new ApiResource()
            {
                Name = "API",
                DisplayName = "display",
                ApiSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256()),
                    new Secret
                    {
                        Value = "4A04D56554F731CCD123BB574D6918C8C83BDF65",
                        Type = "X509Thumbprint",
                        Description = "Certificate"
                    }
                },
                Scopes = new List<string>(){"postman Web API"},
                Enabled = true,
                UserClaims =
                {
                    JwtClaimTypes.Name,
                    JwtClaimTypes.Email,
                    JwtClaimTypes.Subject,
                    JwtClaimTypes.Role,
                    JwtClaimTypes.Address,
                    JwtClaimTypes.Confirmation,
                    JwtClaimTypes.EmailVerified,
                    JwtClaimTypes.Id,
                    JwtClaimTypes.Profile
                }
            },
```

Comment: Right now I do not have any clients consuming the IDP,  I am looking at the result that is coming back which is the Principal.Identity and Principal.Claims.   I added the scope for Roles and still, i do not see the list of roles within the identity.